# Rtabmap reference frame with ur5 and Kinect v2

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've been trying to create a collision map of the surroundings (with rtabmap) for a Universal Robot ur5 using a Microsoft Kinect v2 mounted to an elbow close to the end effector of the robot.
I am using ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

I have written a .launch file that starts up all the nodes. Most of the elements of the algorithm are working fine, except that I don't seem to get the reference frame for the map right....
What do I need to link the map frame to in order to get the mapping in reference to the robot right even when it's moving (I've written a motion_publisher node that makes the robot follow a trajectory for looking around so as to map the whole area around it).

This is the .launch file I'm using:

```
<launch>

<!--By default , the database db is not started -->
    <arg name ="db" default ="false"/>

<!--By default , debug mode is switched off -->
    <arg name ="debug" default ="false" />

<!-- Load the URDF , SRDF and other . yaml configuration files on the param server -->
    <include file ="$(find ur5_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch">
        <arg name ="load_robot_description" value ="true"/>
    </include>

<!--Including Kinect Bridge camera driver-->
    <include file ="$(find kinect2_bridge)/launch/kinect2_bridge.launch">
    <arg name ="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    </include>

<!--static_transform_publisher (transformation description) frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms-->
    <!-- Link kinect2_base_link frame to ee_link -->
    <node pkg ="tf"
    type ="static_transform_publisher"
    name ="kinect2_base_link_tf_broadcaster"
        args ="-0.09 0 0.07 0 0 0 ee_link kinect2_base_link 10"/>

    <!-- Link map frame to ee_link -->
    <node pkg ="tf"
    type ="static_transform_publisher"
    name ="map_tf_broadcaster"
        args ="-0.09 0 0.07 0 0 0 ee_link map 10"/>

<!-- Run UR5 drivers with ip of plugged in robot to connect to it-->
   <include file ="$(find ur_modern_driver)/launch/ur5_bringup.launch">
        <arg name ="robot_ip" value ="192.168.100.200"/>
        <!--<arg name ="limited" value ="true" />-->
        <param name ="reverse_port" value ="REVERSE_PORT"/>
    </include>

<!--Run the MoveIt config for the ur5-->
        <include file ="$(find ur5_moveit_config)/launch/ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch">
            <arg name ="limited" value ="false"/>
        </include>

<!--Run Rviz and load the saved config to see the state of the move_group node-->
    <node pkg="rviz" 
    type="rviz" 
    name="my_rviz" 
    args="-d $(find MotionPublisher)/launch/rvizconfig_qhdkinect.rviz"/>           

            <!--Starting up rtabmap in mapping mode-->
    <include file ="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/rgbd_mapping_kinect2.launch">
    <arg name ="resolution" value="qhd"/>
    </include>

<!--Start Motion Publisher to publish trajectory points for mapping-->
    <node name ="MotionPublisher_node" 
        pkg ="MotionPublisher" 
        type ="MotionPublisher_node"/>
</launch>
```

With the current configuration (as shown in the .launch file above) the mapping seems to work fine for a while, but after some movements the map seems to loose track... objects are appearing multiple times at different angles from the robot and the map usually shifts to a weird angle from the robot (mostly some sort of an inclined plane to the robots base plane).

To me it looks like the transformations aren't calculated correctly.
Sure enough I do get "[ERROR] Found empty JointState message" every now and then... not sure where it's coming from and if there's a connection!

I am not entirely sure if my setup is correct neither... might just be that I need to connect some frames differently!

Unfortunately I'm missing Karma to attach the tf view_frames output... if you upvote my question I'll be able to attach it ;)

Any help is very much appreciated, kind of at a loss at the moment.
Not sure where to look any further!
Thanks all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270756/rtabmap-reference-frame-with-ur5-and-kinect-v2/) by [budekatude](https://answers.ros.org/users/31120/budekatude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-12**:\

> ```
> <param name ="reverse_port" value ="REVERSE_PORT"/>
> ```

Just noticed this: `REVERSE_PORT` is not a valid value for the `reverse_port` parameter. If you don't *need* it (ie: you have only a single robot and don't have a restrictive firewall), don't specify that parameter. It will use a default.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-12**:\

> Unfortunately I'm missing Karma to attach the tf view_frames output.

I've given you enough karma now.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-09-12**:
Is the arm fixed on a mobile base or a static base? What is the base frame of the platform? You would have to set frame_id of rgbd_mapping_kinect2.launch to this frame, otherwise the map is built against kinect frame, not the base frame.

**Comment by [budekatude](https://answers.ros.org/users/31120/budekatude/) on 2017-09-13**:
Thanks for all the input (and the Karma gvdhoorn :D )!
Turns out matlabbes answer took the price and it's working perfectly now!!
@matlabbe: if you want to post your solution as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as the best solution!
Thanks again everyone for your input! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Here is the copy of my comment above for convenience)

What is the base frame of the platform? You would have to set `frame_id` of [rgbd_mapping_kinect2.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rgbd_mapping_kinect2.launch) to this frame, otherwise the map is built against kinect frame, not the base frame.

For example, if the base frame of the robot is `base_footprint`, the launch above would look like this:

```
<include file ="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/rgbd_mapping_kinect2.launch">
    <arg name ="resolution" value="qhd"/>
    <arg name="frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
</include>
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1